# Linq aggregate on accumulated bool values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with strings:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

strList.Add("first");
strList.Add("second");
strList.Add("third");
strList.Add("fourth");
```

I need to send two strings on every iteration to some method that returns `bool` and finally tell what was the result.

For instance:

- First iteration: "first", "second" (returns true)
- Second iteration: "second", "third" (returns true)
- Third iteration: "third", "fourth" (returns false)

So return value from all calls is `false` (performing `"&&"` between those return values) .

I have to use LINQ so I've try to do something like:

```
strList.Aggregate<bool>((prev, current) => Method(prev,current));
```

but unfortunately I'm doing something wrong.

**Further explanation:**

I want to call bool Method(string, string) for all successive string pairs in strList and get the boolean && of all the results

Comment: Improve your specifications. "So return value from all calls is false". Yet your first and second iteration return true.

Comment: @HaraldDutch: OP wants to call `bool Method(string, string)` for all successive `string` pairs in `strList`, and get the boolean `&&` of all the results.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to short-circuit (i.e. stop evaluating after first `false` value), or evaluate until the end of the list and return the final result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way might be to create the pairs, and then call `Enumerable.All` to see if any of them is false:

```
// create tuples
var pairs = strList
    .Zip(strList.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);

// check if all are true
var result = pairs.All(p => Method(p.Item1, p.Item2));
```

However, this is short-circuting (will stop evaluating after the first `false` is encountered), and after the edit, it seems you want to evaluate the whole list.

In that case, you can use [`Aggregate<Tuple<string>, bool>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) (i.e. the overload which has an accumulator of a different type) after you've got the tuples. Start with `true`, and use the boolean `&`:

```
var finalResult = strList
    .Zip(strList.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
    .Aggregate(true, (val, tuple) => Method(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item1) & val);
```

If your method would accept a `Tuple`, it would perhaps be slightly more readable.

Comment: The unfortunate bit about using linq for these adjacent type comparisons is that the implementation rarely short circuits. `All` will stop once it finds a false, but not until after you've zipped the entire collection into pairs.

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers: Why do you say it "rarely" short circuits? Quite the opposite, LINQ is lazy in all its methods, and no tuples will be created after the first `false` result (in the first example, of course). Just like `pairs` by itself will not evaluate anything. Or, for example, `pairs.First()` will only create a single tuple.

Comment: One has to be careful with `&&` because it short-circuits, which OP doesn't want. For example, your answer stops evaluating after the first `false`, because `val.Item2` is `false` from that point on. Swapping the order will fix the issue, but I wanted to spare OP from these issues.

Comment: Oops missed that. Makes me wonder what OP is really trying to do though.

Comment: Sorry, I must have had a `ToList` in the last linq question sample I debugged through. Zip and even Enumerable.Range do short-circuit/evaluate as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a [different overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Aggregate` and avoids the `Zip()`, but assumes you code `Method` in such a way to handle the initial empty string as parted of the seeded tuple.

```
        var result = strList.Aggregate(
            Tuple.Create("", true),
            (val, current) => Tuple.Create(current, val.Item2 & Method(val.Item1, current)),
            val => val.Item2);
```

You can see this at work using [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NizuVt). It does not handle a case of only 1 item in the list, but then, neither does the accepted answer. I guess we can assume that will be protected by a check somewhere.